# Scala - error: type not found

Tags: scala, types

I am a newbie in Scala and  I have an error that i cannot understand. Here is my `array` of `int` : (numbers from 1 to 100)

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
```

Next I wrote a function, which is returning the MAX value of my array:

```
rdd.reduce((x, y) => x > y ? x : y)
```

But I always get this error:

```
<console>:30: error: not found: type y
              rdd.reduce((x, y) => x > y ? x : y)
                                               ^
```

I don't really know what the error means so i can't find a solution. But if i use my function like this, it works:

```
rdd.reduce((x, y) => if(x > y) x else y)
```

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: What is `sc.parallelize`? Is this from Spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `? :` operator in Scala, use `if` instead:

```
rdd.reduce((x, y) => if (x > y) x else y)
```

Or use `max` instead of building it on your own:

```
rdd.reduce((x, y) => x max y)
```

Or with _ syntax for anonymous function:

```
rdd.reduce(_ max _)
```

Or avoid building collection max on your own:

```
rdd.max
```